# How can I disable a button in twilio flex?

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

in some cases, I need to disable and enable a button that is part of Twilio Flex. For example, I would like to enable and disable the button that shows the worker directory. I don't want to remove it, I just want it to be blocked.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQnX5.png)

I have tried to modify the state of the button to disabled = "true" but I have not achieved anything successfully